# Reusing the connection and prepare statement to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having a function which calls different functions that connect to the mysql database and queries the database. Here I am not sure how can I reuse my `conn and cmd` to make more efficiency in the code. To have the connection creaeted in `Validation()` once and reuse them in the other function wherever I am trying to connect to database. Below is what I am doing

```
    private static void Validation(List<Employee> EmpList, string Group)
    {
        ValidateName(EmpList, Group);
        ValidateDept(EmpList, Group);
     }
    public static void ValidateName(List<Employee> EmpList, string Grp)
    {
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string selectQuery;

        for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
        {
           selectQuery = "Select Name from Employee where Group = @Group  AND @Name in (FirstName, LastName);";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Grp;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmpList[i].Name;
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lineList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                if (lineList.Count <=0)
                {
                   WriteValidationFailure(EmpList[i], "Failed");
                }
                conn.Close();
        }       
      }
    }

   public static void ValidateBreedingDept(List<Employee> EmpList, string Grp)
    {
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string selectQuery;

        for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
        {
            selectQuery = "Select DepartmentName from Department where Group = @Group AND DepartmentName = @Dept;";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Grp;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dept", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmpList[i].Dept;
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lineList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                if (lineList.Count <= 0)
                {
                    WriteValidationFailure(listOfMouse[i], "Failed");
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am new to connecting to database and querying from c#. And also how to rewrite the queries to use Prepare statements. I understand I can use `cmd.Prepare()` but can I reuse the parameters from one function in to another.

Answer (score 1):

"reuse my conn and cmd to make more efficiency in the code"

You don't need to worry about that. C# takes care of it by using something called connection pool.

All "closed" connections do not really close the underlying connection but rather returned to the connection pool for later use which is exactly what you are trying to do

[Read more on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)